# How to take voltage source from an AC circuit?

Tags: ac

How to take a small amount of voltage (6 or 12vdc) from a 24VAC closed circuit to feed a small device (6 or 12vdc coil draws less than 100 mA) ? 
[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to (1) assign numbers to "small", (2) what current you require, (3) whether it is DC or AC, (4) what voltage stability / tolerance is required and (5) what the load is.

Comment: Done, thank you.

Comment: You missed (2), the current required or the resistance of the coil. "small" is not a value. There should be a space before each '('.

Comment: OK. You've got a good question now.

Comment: Use a bridge rectifier IC (50 volts) and use a 2200uf capacitor. Then use a buck converter. 24 volt AC will create approximately 24x1.414 volt DC. If you want then I will provide details circuit diagram. Google, YouTube has enough resources related to this.

Comment: @Sadat Rafi, I'm waiting for your full answer with circuit diagram. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A DC relay coil doesn't require a stable DC voltage. A full-wave rectified voltage will suffice.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fesEK1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A suitable circuit.*

Procedure:

- Connect the bridge rectifier or make one using four diodes.
- Measure the DC voltage on BR1+ and BR1-. This is *V<sub>DC</sub>*.
- Measure the coil resistance of RLY1. This is *R<sub>C</sub>*.
- Note the coil voltage. This is *V<sub>C</sub>*.

Now you can calculate R1.

$$ \frac {V_C} {V_{DC}} = \frac {R_C} {R_1 + R_C} $$

$$ R_1 + R_C = \frac {V_{DC}} {V_{C}} R_C$$

$$ R_1 = \frac {V_{DC}} {V_{C}} R_C - R_C = (\frac {V_{DC}} {V_{C}} - 1) R_C$$

The power rating of the resistor can be calculated by \$ P = VI \$ where *V* is the voltage across the resistor and *I* the current through it. It will get very hot if you run close to rated power so doubling the power rating is usually a good idea.

If you're using a 12 V relay you will probably find that a second one in series with RLY1 will do the job.

---

It now appears that it is a [Shori S3H-12-1C](https://www.tme.eu/ie/en/details/s3h-12-1c/miniature-electromagnetic-relays/shori-electric/) relay. The data page shows that this has a 400 Ω coil which at 12 V will have a current given by \$ I = \frac V R = \frac {12}{400} = 30 \ \text {mA} \$. Anything around 400 Ω series resistance will do the job for you. You'll need to check the power rating but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Output will be 33.9 volt DC ( Approximately), you should include a buck converter. I've seen you have used resistance to limit current. But he wanted 12 volt.

Comment: No it won't. Output will be about 24 V DC full-wave rectified without smoothing. OP is powering a relay so there is no need for smoothing or regulation. If the OP had a 24 V DC relay then a bridge rectifier would be all that was required.

Comment: Then you should include the value of resistance and watt rating. I'll withdraw the downvote few minutes later.

Comment: No, I have provided the means of calculating both of those. The purpose of my answer is to educate, not provide a free design service. Your downvote seems to have been due to an error in your understanding of full-wave rectification.

Comment: @Jasen, OP mentions 12 V and 100 mA in the same sentence. That is a 1.2 W relay coil and 1.2 W in the resistor. I'd be recommending 2 W minimum.

Comment: that's a huge relay.but yeah.

Comment: I've added a picture to the relay. Thank you all for your contributions.

Comment: See the update. You should have researched the datasheet yourself and posted a link in your question. Make it easy for those you are asking to help you!

Answer (score 0):

use a capacitive dropper

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ylEI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 will need to be chosen to match your relay.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've added a photo of the relay I want to use, how can I calculate its Amps from the numbers on top of it?

Comment: @Shaydzmi You need to do a web search for the part number S3H-12-1C and look for the manufacturer's datasheet. It will tell you how much current the coil needs. Be sure to select a capacitor with a low ESR and high ripple current capability.